Do I need to uninstall Miniforge before using a new installer?
I have an installation of Miniforge on Windows 11 (with base environment of Python 3.10.14) and I would like to upgrade it to the latest (with base environment of Python 3.12). What would be the consequences of simply downloading the new installer and running it? Would it run?
I have no problem with it destroying existing environments.
Then again, is there an alternative that would simply upgrade the base environment? In my experience it is better to have a fresh "base".

That depends. have you followed the usual "best practice" advise and have not installed packages to base, but instead to project specific environments? Or is your base completely cluttered with hundreds of packages? In the latter case, a fresh install (uninstall + reinstall) might be better. In the first case, just try
conda install -n base python=3.12

to upgrade python in your base to the latest version.
